# How to hide all TR whit especific TD?

Tags: jquery

Look this table.

```
<table id='tab'>
    <tr><td>AAA</td><td class='hidable'>BBB</td></tr>
    <tr><td>CCC</td><td>DDD</td></tr>
    <tr><td>EEE</td><td>FFF</td></tr>
    <tr><td>GGG</td><td class='hidable'>HHH</td></tr>
    <tr><td>III</td><td class='hidable'>JJJ</td></tr>
    <tr><td>KKK</td><td>LLL</td></tr>
    <tr><td>MMM</td><td class='hidable'>NNN</td></tr>
</table>
```

In this table, how can I hide all TR that contains a TD with class = 'hidable'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/):

```js
$('#tab tr').has('td.hidable').hide();
```

Comment: Yes!!! It's greate. Thank ypu.

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking for how to do this with pure JS:

Consider the following code:

```
<script>
let trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
let tds;
trs.forEach(tr =>{ 
  tds=tr.querySelectorAll("td");
  tds.forEach( td =>{
    if(td.hasAttribute("class", "hidable")){
     tr.setAttribute("hidden","");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope you find this useful!